# Why do none of my players want to extend their contact?

Tags: football-manager-2014

None of my current players seem to want to extend their contacts that are expiring at the end of the month. I brought them out of the Skrill South into the Skrill Premier, along with an FA Trophy. Most of my interactions (team talks/ team meetings) have seemed positively received.

Am I not good enough for them anymore?

Comment: Are you handling negotiations yourself or having assistant manager/director of football do it?

Answer (score 2):

They may feel, with all that success, that they are now bigger than the club and should be moving on. Ideally, you probably shouldn't have left them hanging until one month before the end of their contracts either.

I think the reputation of your players grows much faster than the reputation of your club.